# Помогите пожалуйста по Паскалю

Tags: pascal

1)Работа посвящена обработке целых чисел путем использования основных операторов.
Цель работы. Изучить операции обработки целых чисел и основные циклические структуры, используя их научиться составлять алгоритмы. 
Замечание. Для выполнения работы использовать только переменные целого типа.

**Вариант 17. Дано натуральное число N, получить число M, каждая цифра которого в сумме с соответствующей цифрой числа N равна 10 (Например, N=123, M=987; N=4307, M=6703).**

Comment: @Азат на данном форуме не приветствуется решение учебных задач за учащихся. Если при решении этой задачи вы столкнулись с какими-то трудностями, то опишите их и приведите код, который написали вы сами

Comment: 123 надо вычитать из 1110, т.к. все символы кроме последнего занимают десятки у соседа. Для прохода в цикле по числу используй mod и div.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

переведи в стринг, разбей на каждый символ, их потом конвертируй в интеджер и из 10 вычитай это число, собери в нужном порядке и будет тебе счастье :3

Comment: @handbat0, отличный пример классического индусского подхода :)

Comment: В задании же ясно сказано - для выполнения работы использовать только переменные целого типа.

Answer (score 0):

Придумал алгоритм, не удержался от того, чтобы написать. Чтобы не лишать паскалистов последней возможности сделать домашнее задание самостоятельно, реализация будет не на паскале.

```java
public static int getComplementary(final int number) {
    int result = number;
    int i = 10;
    while (result > 0) {
        result -= i;
        i *= 10;
    }

    return result * -1;
}
```